# Why is Rails 5.0.1 injecting an iframe in my html that interferes with links in the header nav bar?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm checking out what's new in Rails 5 by going through Michael Hartl's tutorial for that version. By the end of chapter 7 I noticed the links in the nav bar work only when I click below them. Bringing up the web inspector shows that something has injected a `div.lpiframeoverlay/iframe#lpiframeNNNNNNNN/#document/html` tag that seems to serve no purpose other than to capture events.

Searching for `lpiframeoverlay` on `github.com/rails` found nothing, so it's most likely due to one of the libraries the code loads.

The generated source has a `@media print` rule to hide `.lpiframeoverlay`, so I just did the same in general. Problem solved, but what's this thing for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is coming from the chrome extension LastPass. https://gist.github.com/anstosa/4745722

Try disabling that and then give it another shot.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. Since the code I'm using is online I'll see if I can file a bug with lastpass on it.